# How to make a complex count of unique queries

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm trying to get a specific type of count from `MySQL` / `SQL` database.  The table has a column of records which are IDs and a second which is another reference ID.  Some of the reference IDs are integers and some have text in them.  Similar to this:

```
ID  | RefID
123 | 1234567
123 | 1234568
123 | 1234569
123 | ABC/US12/12345
123 | ABC/AA12/12345
123 | ABC/BB12/12345
```

If the number is integer, it represents the USA.
For text IDs the "ABC" part is always the same but the "AA" and "BB" represent country codes. Sometimes it's "US" such as "ABC/US12/12345".

For each ID, I want a count of of unique countries for their respective reference IDs. I guess this will use the `DISTINCT RefID` and look something like this:

```
SELECT ID, count(DISTINCT RefID)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID;
```

Except that instead of simply `count(DISTINCT RefID)` I would like DISTINCT to be relative to any integer RefID or RefID with `SUBSTRING(RefID, 5, 2)` = "US", and else `DISTINCT` should be `DISTINCT(SUBSTRING(RefID, 5, 2))` for the RefID. So the count for the data above would be `3`.

Can anyone give me a start on what this type of function is called or how to accomplish this?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_. Remove those extra brackets to make code clearer, i.e. simply `count(DISTINCT RefID)`.

Comment: OK, it's good to know that. I have clarified the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is close to correct.
Infact, the requirement is to change all integer RefIDs to "US", and then extract the country code from all other RefIDs.

Here is the correct method:

```
SELECT 
ID, 
COUNT(DISTINCT 
    CASE 
    WHEN RefID REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 'US'
    ELSE SUBSTRING(RefID, 5, 2)
    END
) CountryCount
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY CountryCount DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RefID REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN 'US'
                           WHEN RefID LIKE '%/US%' THEN 'US'
                           ELSE RefID
                      END)
FROM CONTINUITYCHILD_P
GROUP BY ID;
```

You may need additional logic if you need to extract countries from other `RefID`s.